# How do I use XSLT and XPath to group an already filtered set of nodes by their parent node using templates

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given this XML, I need to display items in a single category, grouped under the group's heading. Empty groups should not be displayed (e.g. when the category is equal to x, group C 's heading should not be displayed, same for category z and group A and B).

```
<group name="A">
  <item name="A1" category="x"/>
  <item name="A2" category="x"/>
  <item name="A3" category="y"/>
</group>
<group name="B">
  <item name="B1" category="x"/>
</group>
<group name="C">
  <item name="C1" category="y"/>
  <item name="C2" category="z"/>
</group>
```

Because I can't show empty groups, I have already filtered the items into $items. This set I pass as a param to the template that renders the groupings (see below). In this template, for each grouping I need call a template to render the items in the current group.

```
<xsl:template name="groups">

  <!-- This is already filtered by category -->
  <xsl:param name="items" />

  <!-- Select only the groups that should be displayed -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$items/parent::group">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="./@name"/></h1>

    <!-- Display all filtered items in this group -->
    <div class="items">
      <xsl:call-template name="items">
        <!-- How can I get the items from $items for the current group? -->
        <xsl:with-param name="partners" select="$items..."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

What do I select for the `param` that I pass to the `items` template?

The template to display all items:

```
<xsl:template name="items">
  <xsl:param name="items" />

  <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <div class="item">
      <xsl:value-of select="./@name" />
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The end result when filtered for category z should be:

```
<h1>C</h1>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">C2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation produces the desired result for all categories:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCatByVal" match="@category" use="."/>
 <xsl:key name="kGroupByCat" match="group" use="item/@category"/>
 <xsl:key name="kItemByGroupAndCat" match="item"
  use=" concat(generate-id(..), '+', @category)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDistCats" select=
  "/*/*/*/@category
            [generate-id() = generate-id(key('kCatByVal', .)[1])]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDistCats"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@category">
 <h1>Category <xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kGroupByCat', .)">
   <xsl:with-param name="pCat" select="."/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="group">
  <xsl:param name="pCat"/>
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h1>
  <div class="items">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "item
      [generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kItemByGroupAndCat',
                        concat(generate-id(..), '+', $pCat)
                        )
                    )]"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <div class="item"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document** (with all severe malformedness corrected):

```
<t>
    <group name="A">
        <item name="A1" category="x"/>
        <item name="A2" category="x"/>
        <item name="A3" category="y"/>
    </group>
    <group name="B">
        <item name="B1" category="x"/>
    </group>
    <group name="C">
        <item name="C1" category="y"/>
        <item name="C2" category="z"/>
    </group>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<h1>Category x</h1>
<h1>A</h1>
<div class="items">
   <div class="item">A1</div>
</div>
<h1>B</h1>
<div class="items">
   <div class="item">B1</div>
</div>
<h1>Category y</h1>
<h1>A</h1>
<div class="items">
   <div class="item">A3</div>
</div>
<h1>C</h1>
<div class="items">
   <div class="item">C1</div>
</div>
<h1>Category z</h1>
<h1>C</h1>
<div class="items">
   <div class="item">C2</div>
</div>
```

**and this is displayed in the browser as**:

## Category x

## A

A1

## B

B1

## Category y

## A

A3

## C

C1

## Category z

## C

C2

Comment: When you say this works, I believe you. Except I have no idea *how* it works. What I found out is that there's a really simple way to do it: `$items[parent::Group[@name = current()/@name]]`. This selects only items from the filtered items that have the current group as their parent, so it can be passed in as the value of the param. With this solution there's no need for generating keys.

Comment: @michielvoo, I will add an explanation when I find some free time (going to work shortly). What this solution has more than what is in your question (how would anyone know in advance what categories will be there in the XML document???), is that it first determines all distinct valye for `@category`, then for each of these distinct category values, the transformation produces the wanted projection of the XML document.